# Undefined counter value in simulation

Tags: signals, undefined, vhdl, counter

I am very new to VHDL and as a part of a university project, I am trying to create a statemachine with four states. I wrote some VHDL Code and a testbench, but I could not yet confirm if the statemachine works at all, but I will verify this after I solved the current problem:

Part of the statemachine is an unsigned counter which should determine, whether to fetch data to a highbyte or a low byte. In my testbench, I just want to confirm if this counter works at all. Right now, after being initialized with 0, when the counting process starts the first time, I receive an undefined Value as the counter value.

At first, I tried to implement the counter as a std_logic_vector, but I understood, why this could not work (without cast). So I switched to unsigned and expected the counter to work.
By commenting single processes out I found out, that the counting process produces problems with the process "change status" and "change_current_state". But I just can't figure out why these processes interfere with each other.
"change_current_state" never reaches the "RESET" if - statement in my testbench, so it can't assign a value to the counter. Also, the process "change_status" never reaches the elsif - statement with the state being "prepareData" This is the only statement in which a value is assigned to the counter.

VHDL Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity readFromADC is
    Port
        (
            CLK_IN  :   in  std_logic;
            RESET_IN_N  :   in std_logic;
            BUSY_IN :   in  std_logic;
            DATA_IN :   in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            ACK_ERROR_IN    :   in std_logic;

            ENABLE_I2C  :   out std_logic;
            ADDR_I2C    :   out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
            RW_I2C      :   out std_logic;
            DATA_WR_I2C :   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

            DATA_OUT :  out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            SHIFT_OUT_RDY   :   out std_logic;

            SHOWSTATE : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0); -- debugging
            BYTECOUNTER: out unsigned (1 downto 0)
        );
end readFromADC;

architecture readFromADC_arch of readFromADC is

    constant const_data_wr    :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    constant const_rw_I2C :   std_logic := '1';
    constant const_addr_I2C :   std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := "0101000";
    constant const_da2_control   :   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";

    type states is
        (
            idle,
            read,
            prepareData,
            shiftOut
        );
    signal sign_clk :   std_logic;

    signal sign_HighByte    :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal sign_LowByte    :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    signal current_state :   states;
    signal next_state :   states;

    signal sign_data_out :  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal sign_ena_i2c : std_logic := '0'; 
    signal sign_count_bytes_uns : unsigned (1 downto 0) := "00"; 
    signal prepare_data_rdy :   std_logic := '0';
    signal sign_shift_out_rdy    :   std_logic := '0'; 
    signal debug_states         :   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);

begin
    --Zuweisungen
    sign_clk <= CLK_IN;   

    ENABLE_I2C <= sign_ena_i2c;
    ADDR_I2C <= const_addr_I2C;
    RW_I2C <= const_rw_I2C;  
    DATA_WR_I2C <= const_data_wr;

    DATA_OUT <= sign_data_out;
    SHIFT_OUT_RDY   <= sign_shift_out_rdy;

    SHOWSTATE <= debug_states;
    BYTECOUNTER <= sign_count_bytes_uns;

    --nächsten Status zuweisen
    change_current_state : process (sign_clk, RESET_IN_N)
    begin
        if rising_edge(sign_clk) then
            if (RESET_IN_N = '0') then
                current_state <= idle;
                sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
                sign_data_out <= (others => '0');
                sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";
            else
                current_state <= next_state;       
            end if;
        end if;
    end process change_current_state;

    --Status ändern
    change_status : process (current_state)
    begin
      if current_state = idle then
            debug_states <= "00";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
            prepare_data_rdy <= '0';
            sign_ena_i2c <= '1';
        elsif current_state = read then
            debug_states <= "01";
--            sign_count_bytes <= sign_count_bytes + 1;
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
        elsif current_state = prepareData then
            debug_states <= "10";
            sign_ena_i2c <= '0';
--            sign_count_bytes <= "00";
        elsif current_state = shiftOut then
            sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";
            debug_states <= "11";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '1';
        end if;
    end process change_status;

    acquireData : process (sign_count_bytes_uns, current_state)
    begin
        if current_state = read then
            if (sign_count_bytes_uns = 1) then
                sign_HighByte <= DATA_IN;
            elsif (sign_count_bytes_uns = 2) then
                sign_LowByte <= DATA_IN;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process acquireData;

    gatherData : process (current_state)
    begin
        if current_state = prepareData then
            sign_data_out <= const_da2_control & sign_HighByte(3 downto 0) &  sign_LowByte;
            prepare_data_rdy <= '1';
        end if;
    end process gatherData;

    --Dekodiere den nächsten Status
    next_state_decode: process (current_state, BUSY_IN, ACK_ERROR_IN, sign_count_bytes_uns, prepare_data_rdy, sign_shift_out_rdy)
    begin
        next_state <= current_state;  --Default: behalte den aktuellen Status
        case (current_state) is
            when Idle =>
                if (BUSY_IN = '0') AND (ACK_ERROR_IN = '0') then
                   next_state <= read;
                end if;
             when read =>
                if sign_count_bytes_uns >= 2 then
--                if sign_count_bytes = "11" then
                   next_state <= prepareData;
                end if;
             when prepareData =>
                if prepare_data_rdy = '1' then
                    next_state <= shiftOut;
                end if;
             when shiftOut =>
                if sign_shift_out_rdy = '1' then
                    next_state <= Idle;
                end if;
        end case;      
    end process next_state_decode;

    countBusy : process (BUSY_IN)
    begin
        if falling_edge(BUSY_IN) then
            sign_count_bytes_uns <= sign_count_bytes_uns + 1;
--            if (sign_count_bytes_uns <= 2) then
--                sign_count_bytes <= std_logic_vector (sign_count_bytes_uns);   
            if (sign_count_bytes_uns > 2) then
                sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";
            end if;

        end if;

    end process countBusy;
```

Testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity sim_read_adc is
--  Port ( );
end sim_read_adc;

architecture sim_read_adc_arch of sim_read_adc is
    component readFromADC is
    Port
        (
            CLK_IN  :   in  std_logic;
            RESET_IN_N  :   in std_logic;
            BUSY_IN :   in  std_logic;
            DATA_IN :   in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            ACK_ERROR_IN    :   in std_logic;

            ENABLE_I2C  :   out std_logic;
            ADDR_I2C    :   out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
            RW_I2C      :   out std_logic;
            DATA_WR_I2C :   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

            DATA_OUT :  out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            SHIFT_OUT_RDY   :   out std_logic;

            SHOWSTATE : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            BYTECOUNTER: out unsigned (1 downto 0)
        );
    end component readFromADC;

    signal sim_CLK_IN  :     std_logic;
    signal sim_RESET_IN_N  :   std_logic := '1';
    signal sim_BUSY_IN :    std_logic := '1';
    signal sim_DATA_IN :    std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "10101010";
    signal sim_ACK_ERROR_IN    :   std_logic := '0';

    signal sim_ENABLE_I2C  :   std_logic;
    signal sim_ADDR_I2C    :   std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal sim_RW_I2C      :   std_logic;
    signal sim_DATA_WR_I2C :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    signal sim_DATA_OUT :  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal sim_SHIFT_OUT_RDY   : std_logic;

    signal sim_SHOWSTATE : std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal sim_BYTECOUNTER : unsigned (1 downto 0);
begin
    dut : readFromADC

    port map
        (
            CLK_IN     => sim_CLK_IN, 
            RESET_IN_N => sim_RESET_IN_N,
            BUSY_IN => sim_BUSY_IN,
            DATA_IN => sim_DATA_IN,
            ACK_ERROR_IN => sim_ACK_ERROR_IN,

            ENABLE_I2C => sim_ENABLE_I2C,
            ADDR_I2C => sim_ADDR_I2C,
            RW_I2C => sim_RW_I2C, 
            DATA_WR_I2C => sim_DATA_WR_I2C,

            DATA_OUT => sim_DATA_OUT,
            SHIFT_OUT_RDY => sim_SHIFT_OUT_RDY,

            SHOWSTATE => sim_SHOWSTATE,
            BYTECOUNTER => sim_BYTECOUNTER
        );

    clk_gen : process
    begin
        sim_CLK_IN <= '0';
        wait for 0.5us;
        sim_CLK_IN <= '1';
        wait for 0.5us;
    end process clk_gen;

    generate_busy : process
    begin
        wait for 5us;
        sim_BUSY_IN <= '0';
        wait for 1us;
        sim_BUSY_IN <= '1';
    end process generate_busy;

end sim_read_adc_arch;
```

Simulation(no process is commented out):
[Simulation(no process is commented out)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGk1Y.png)

*EDIT: The updated VHDL - Code (testbench didn't have to be changed):

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity readFromADC is
    Port
        (
            CLK_IN  :   in  std_logic;
            RESET_IN_N  :   in std_logic;
            BUSY_IN :   in  std_logic;
            DATA_IN :   in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            ACK_ERROR_IN    :   in std_logic;

            ENABLE_I2C  :   out std_logic;
            ADDR_I2C    :   out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
            RW_I2C      :   out std_logic;
            DATA_WR_I2C :   out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

            DATA_OUT :  out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
            SHIFT_OUT_RDY   :   out std_logic;

            SHOWSTATE : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0); -- debugging
            BYTECOUNTER: out unsigned (1 downto 0)
        );
end readFromADC;

architecture readFromADC_arch of readFromADC is

    constant const_data_wr    :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
    constant const_rw_I2C :   std_logic := '1';
    constant const_addr_I2C :   std_logic_vector(6 downto 0) := "0101000";
    constant const_da2_control   :   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";

    type states is
        (
            idle,
            read,
            prepareData,
            shiftOut
        );
    signal sign_clk :   std_logic;

    signal sign_HighByte    :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal sign_LowByte    :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

    signal current_state :   states;
    signal next_state :   states;

    signal sign_data_out :  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal sign_ena_i2c : std_logic := '0'; 
    signal sign_count_bytes_uns : unsigned (1 downto 0) := "00"; 
    signal prepare_data_rdy :   std_logic := '0';
    signal sign_shift_out_rdy    :   std_logic := '0'; 
    signal debug_states         :   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);

begin
    --Zuweisungen
    sign_clk <= CLK_IN;   

    ENABLE_I2C <= sign_ena_i2c;
    ADDR_I2C <= const_addr_I2C;
    RW_I2C <= const_rw_I2C;  
    DATA_WR_I2C <= const_data_wr;

    DATA_OUT <= sign_data_out;
    SHIFT_OUT_RDY   <= sign_shift_out_rdy;

    SHOWSTATE <= debug_states;
    BYTECOUNTER <= sign_count_bytes_uns;

    --nächsten Status zuweisen
    change_current_state : process (sign_clk, RESET_IN_N)
    begin
        if rising_edge(sign_clk) then
--            if (RESET_IN_N = '0') then
--                current_state <= idle;
--                sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
--                sign_data_out <= (others => '0');
--                sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";
--            else
            current_state <= next_state;       
--            end if;
        end if;
    end process change_current_state;

    --Status ändern
    change_status : process (current_state)
    begin
      if current_state = idle then
            debug_states <= "00";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
            prepare_data_rdy <= '0';
            sign_ena_i2c <= '1';
        elsif current_state = read then
            debug_states <= "01";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
        elsif current_state = prepareData then
            debug_states <= "10";
            sign_ena_i2c <= '0';
        elsif current_state = shiftOut then
            debug_states <= "11";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '1';
        end if;
    end process change_status;

    acquireData : process (sign_count_bytes_uns, current_state)
    begin
        if current_state = read then
            if (sign_count_bytes_uns = 1) then
                sign_HighByte <= DATA_IN;
            elsif (sign_count_bytes_uns = 2) then
                sign_LowByte <= DATA_IN;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process acquireData;

    gatherData : process (current_state)
    begin
        if current_state = prepareData then
            sign_data_out <= const_da2_control & sign_HighByte(3 downto 0) &  sign_LowByte;
            prepare_data_rdy <= '1';
        end if;
    end process gatherData;

    --Dekodiere den nächsten Status
    next_state_decode: process (current_state, BUSY_IN, ACK_ERROR_IN, sign_count_bytes_uns, prepare_data_rdy, sign_shift_out_rdy)
    begin
        next_state <= current_state;  --Default: behalte den aktuellen Status
        case (current_state) is
            when Idle =>
                if (BUSY_IN = '0') AND (ACK_ERROR_IN = '0') then
                   next_state <= read;
                end if;
             when read =>
                if sign_count_bytes_uns >= 2 then
--                if sign_count_bytes = "11" then
                   next_state <= prepareData;
                end if;
             when prepareData =>
                if prepare_data_rdy = '1' then
                    next_state <= shiftOut;
                end if;
             when shiftOut =>
                if sign_shift_out_rdy = '1' then
                    next_state <= Idle;
                end if;
        end case;      
    end process next_state_decode;

    countBusy : process (BUSY_IN, RESET_IN_N)
    begin
        if falling_edge (RESET_IN_N) then
            sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";

        elsif falling_edge(BUSY_IN) then
            sign_count_bytes_uns <= sign_count_bytes_uns + 1;  
            if (sign_count_bytes_uns > 2) then
                sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";
            end if;

        end if;

    end process countBusy;

end readFromADC_arch;
```

Comment: Also: I know there are a lot of mistakes / bad coding in this, so feel free to tell me about it so I can improve

Comment: It works now, thanks to @Gautitho 's advice. Both the processes "change_current_state" and "change_status" interfered with the counter, so both had to be changed. I will provide my solution in my question. Now I can go on with searching for errors and improving the state machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get some 'X' in simulation usually means that a signal is assigned to 2 (or more) value at the same time. That often implies that you assign this signal in several concurrent process.

In VHDL, it's better to avoid assigning a signal in 2 different process (Note that a line outside of any process is a process).

In your code, the signal *sign_count_bytes_uns* is affected in 3 process. I think you should modify at least 2 of them (by merging them).

But the real reason of your 'X' is a little bit more tricky, in this process :

```
    change_status : process (current_state)
    begin
      if current_state = idle then
            debug_states <= "00";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
            prepare_data_rdy <= '0';
            sign_ena_i2c <= '1';
        elsif current_state = read then
            debug_states <= "01";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '0';
        elsif current_state = prepareData then
            debug_states <= "10";
            sign_ena_i2c <= '0';
        elsif current_state = shiftOut then
            sign_count_bytes_uns <= "00";
            debug_states <= "11";
            sign_shift_out_rdy <= '1';
        end if;
    end process change_status;
```

You assign *sign_count_bytes_uns* in only 1 case and I assume you are not in this case in the simulation screenshot you gave us but *sign_count_bytes_uns* is still to "XX".

The reason is the following : 
When you assign a signal in a process but not in all cases, each time you are not in a case where the signal is affected, this signal will take his previous value (memory). In synthesis, a latch will be infered. So your process *change_status* maintains *sign_count_bytes_uns* to "00" when *countBusy* tries to change it that's why you get some "XX".

Comment: I hope you will understand my explanations. It's a bit tricky and my english is not very clean. Don't hesitate to ask questions if it's not clear to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I will test it tomorrow at work! And I understood your explanation without any problems at all. I knew that the problem had to be two simultaneous assignments, but I just couldn't figure out, why that happened. I assumed that in every case the signal is not directly assigned in the code, the value would just not change. So also for future projects, your explanation was very helpful. Also, I will rework my code so that each signal will only be assigned in one process

Comment: Nice ! Little tip : each time you are in combinationnal process (no memory), assign all outputs (signals assigned in the process) of this process at start of the process with default values which will be overwritten later in the process. It prevents this kind of errors.

Comment: If I may add one question which is not directly related to the question I asked: In a design which consists of several modules, is it better to have one module that deals with the clock division for all other modules and provides the clock for them, or is it better when every single module gets the clock signal from the board and divides the clock themselves?

Comment: If you are sure to use the same clocks in all modules, I think it's better to have only one clock divider (In FPGA, you can use a constructor IP which will be optimized for this application), it reduced logic. But I am not very confident in my answer so try to get a more sure answer.